# jQuery: How to prepend an OPTION within multiple SELECT elements if it's already not there?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I'll explain my situation with the codes.

HTML:

```
<div class="list1">
  <select class="select250">
    <option class="temp" selected="selected" name="filter[]">Select</option>
    <option class="" value="George" name="filter[]">George</option>
    <option class="" value="Ben" name="filter[]">Ben</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="list2">
  <select class="select251">
    <option class="temp" selected="selected" name="filter[]">Select</option>
    <option class="" value="Sarah" name="filter[]">Sarah</option>
    <option class="" value="Alex" name="filter[]">Alex</option>
    <option class="" value="Natalie" name="filter[]">Natalie</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="list3">
  <select class="select252">
    <option class="temp" selected="selected" name="filter[]">Select</option>
    <option class="" value="Mobile" name="filter[]">Mobile</option>
    <option class="" value="Car" name="filter[]">Car</option>
    <option class="" value="Computer" name="filter[]">Computer</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

JS (this is used within PHP):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.select<?php echo $sid?>').change(function() {
    $('.temp', this).remove();  // THIS IS FINE
    if ($('option').siblings('.temp')) { } 
    else { $('select').prepend('<option name="filter[]" selected="selected" class="temp">Select</option>');  // THIS IS NOT WORKING 
    }
  });
</script>
```

What I wanted to do is - whenever an option is selected, it should remove the "Select" option within that list but still keep "Select" option on other lists. This part seems to be working fine. The next thing to do is - when an option is selected on another list, it should bring back select on all the other lists except for the one where it is selected. I tried writing a code for it as you can see above but couldn't move past it. If someone can guide me in the right direction, that'll be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why, but I always get the willies when I see php and js being mixed like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.. This can still be optimized..

```
$('[class^=select]').on('change', function() {
    $('.temp', this).remove();
    var $that = $(this);
    $('select').not($that).each(function() {
        if (!$(this).find('option.temp').length > -1) {
            $(this).prepend('<option name="filter[]" selected="selected" class="temp">Select</option>');
        }
    });
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/qk9MG/1/)**

Comment: That's great- your Fiddle code works! Exactly what I needed. Your Fiddle code is a bit different from the code you've pasted above. Your above line: if (!$(this).find('option.temp').length > -1) does not work. I had to either use > 0 or not use that at all (like in your Fiddle code).

Comment: I just noticed that in Opera and IE browsers, your code does not seem to work. Try your Fiddle code in Opera and IE. Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: I tried testing it in IE7, IE8 and IE9 and it seems to be working for me..  Put the starts with attribute selector inside Quotes and try again $('[class^="select"]')

Comment: That's odd. I tried it in IE9 and Opera. It does not reset the remaining dropdowns to "Select" after a dropdown has been selected. I also tried as you've suggested but it has no effect. Is anyone else having this issue in their browsers?

Comment: If that the case.. Why not use a common class for all the selects you want this to be affected for.. Then try $('.classname') and check if that works

Comment: I tried your suggestion in your Fiddle code. It works in IE but still does not work in Opera. Does Opera handle things differently?

Comment: Adding $(this).val(""); line seems to solve the problem in all browsers. In IE it reverts back to a blank option rather than the prepended option but I can live with that. Works in Opera too. Just does not work in older versions of IE but that's fine. [Modified code here](http://jsfiddle.net/qk9MG/4/)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
$('select').not($(this)).each(function() {
 if ($(this).find('.temp').size() > 0) continue;

 $(this).prepend('<option class="temp" ... </option>');
});
```